# Best method to implement HTML signature

Tags: mail.app

At the company I work for we have an HTML signature using the default mail client from IOS/Mac OS. We want to have a different picture in the signature every season (santa hat for christmas for example). But the problem is there seems to be some kind of caching on the signatures.

The current problem is that we changed the image back to our regular picture but on Iphone it still shows the santa hat when on desktop it shows the right image.

Now I am looking for a different/better way to implement a signature. Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Kind regards,
Robbert

Comment: Can you add two examples of the HTML code used in the past?

Comment: @nohillside Its basic table html. Nothing special to it. So I doubt adding the code will add value to my question. If you disagree, I can see if I can gather a small example.

Comment: The key question probably is whether the link to the picture is always the same (and you just replace the picture on the server with another one having the same name). This would explain why mail clients might keep showing the previous version.

Comment: OTOH, after rereading your question, it doesn't seem to be totally clear whether this issue is on the sender site (when you compose a mail) or on the receiver side. Can you clarify?

Comment: @nohillside The plan was to have a static link in the email signature. On the server side we wanted to change the image without having to keep changing the email signature. The older image most of the times shows up on the reciever side of the email.

Comment: My assumption is that a static link will not work as the client won‘t refresh the image each time. Try a different link for each image.

Comment: @nohillside I know that will work but that is the whole question about. I would like to do it automatically. ]

Comment: Currently your question asks for a different approach than the one you are currently using, without showing the current approach, and without any mention of automation  if you are planning to automatically deploy email signatures to a bunch of Macs and wonder how to do this, please ask specifically.

Comment: @nohillside No my question asks if there is a way to for example disable caching on the signatures. Not automatically deploy anything to anything. I just want to switch an image on a server and make it show up properly in the mail signatures.

Comment: Right now your question asks for „Now I am looking for a different/better way to implement a signature. Does anyone have a better solution for this?“. Might be worth an edit if this isn‘t what you need.